# Started GNOME Display Manager Issue on Ubuntu 18.04.02

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

I am facing issue after my ubuntu patch update. The black screen is coming with Started GNOME Display Manager [OK]. I have tried all the below steps.

1. I did the changes on boot to recovery mode

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

```
# WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

2. Opened the Grub in boot terminal with repalcing nomodeset single with quite splash. But unable to update the lightdm.
   I tried with internet dhclient to set up internet and echo 8.8.8.8 of google but still unable to do it.
3. I have tried to run it in lower kernel 4.15.0.45 version before 1 week it was running but after reboot that also gone.

My kernel is 4.15.0.46 . This machine having 3 Nvidia GPUs. I have set up with Cuda 10 & CudNN 7.4

Please help me. Feel free to ask if any clarification required.

Answer (score 0):

By Using the USB Flash Drive, I created a ISO Ubuntu boot stick. 
By the help of boot stick, I choose the last option during installation to override my old installation without any lose of data.

I got my work space back with all the data. 
I just got to do the rework on Nvidia driver installation with new Kernel.
Cuda and cuDNN are already there.No need to reinstall.
I am able to continue my work but one more issue.
On reboot i am getting complete black page after login to Desktop from Ubuntu.
So i am managing to go inside by recovery mode ...

Any help to resolve the black screen would be appreciated.